# Find all records that never had status = SUCCESSFUL

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I have some processes running within the backend and we are logging it in DB with its status. Now I need to find all processes that never ran successfully since last month.

**Example table:**

```
PID        executiondate  Status
1          2021-06-15     FAILED.       <- PID 1 was successful, but in last month 
1          2021-06-05     FAILED
1          2021-06-01     FAILED
1          2021-05-01     SUCCESSFUL  
2          2021-06-15     SUCCESSFUL    <- PID 2 was successful failed within month
2          2021-06-05     FAILED
2          2021-06-01     SUCCESSFUL
3          2021-06-15     FAILED        <- PID 3 only fails
3          2021-06-05     FAILED
3          2021-06-01     FAILED
4          2021-06-15     SUCCESSFUL    <- PID 4 only successful
4          2021-06-05     SUCCESSFUL
4          2021-06-01     SUCCESSFUL
```

**Condition:**

- I am running a query on 16-06-2021
- To Find only failed PIDs last month (16-06-2021 to 16-05-2021)

**Expected Result:**

- PID 1 and PID 3

**My try:**

- Tried to get the count of status for each PID and then findings record having 1 count and failed status. But it did not work.

  ```
   WITH dataset_by_status AS
   (
            SELECT   pid,
                 Count(*) AS counter,
                 status
            FROM     exampletable
            WHERE    (
                          status = 'FAILED'
                 OR       status = 'SUCCESSFUL')
            AND      executiondate >= (Now() - interval '1 MONTH')
            GROUP BY status
            ORDER BY pid )
   SELECT   pid,
            count(*) AS counter
   FROM     dataset_by_status
   WHERE    status = 'FAILED'
   GROUP BY pid
   HAVING   count(*) = 1
  ```

Comment: `AND NOT EXISTS(... select from table t where t.result = 'success' and t.pid = pid_table.pid)`?

Comment: please share the insert script for this data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want all PIDs that have no 'SUCCESSFUL' in the last ~30 days. To find them, aggregate per PID and make sure you don't find such a row for it.

```
select pid
from exampletable
group by pid
having count(*) filter (where status = 'SUCCESSFUL'
                          and executiondate >= now() - interval '1 month') = 0;
```

If you want to add a counter for the failures in the date range:

```
select pid, count(*) filter (where status = 'FAILED'
                             and executiondate >= now() - interval '1 month') as failed
```

If on the other hand, you want to restrict this to PIDs that have entries in the last ~30 days, move the date range condition to `WHERE`:

```
select pid, count(*) filter (where status = 'FAILED') as failed
from exampletable
where executiondate >= now() - interval '1 month'
group by pid
having count(*) filter (where status = 'SUCCESSFUL') = 0;
```

Comment: Sorry, the comment was posted by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You can use not exists to remove all the pid against which there is at least one entry with "successful" status.

```
      SELECT   pid,
           Count(*) AS counter,
           status
      FROM     exampletable a
      WHERE    (
                    status = 'FAILED'
           OR       status = 'SUCCESSFUL')
      AND      executiondate >= (Now() - interval '1 MONTH')
      and not exists (select 1 from exampletable b where a.pid=b.pid and b.status = 'SUCCESSFUL')
      GROUP BY status
      ORDER BY pid
```

And I think below condition is also not necessary in where clause if there are rows only with 'FAILED' and 'SUCCESSFUL' status.

(
status = 'FAILED'
OR       status = 'SUCCESSFUL')

Answer (score 0):

Totally unsuccessful Pids last month

```
      SELECT DISTINCT pid
      FROM  exampletable t1
      WHERE executiondate >= (Now() - interval '1 MONTH')
          AND NOT EXISTS (
              SELECT 1 
              FROM exampletable t2
              WHERE t2.pid = t1.pid and t2.status = 'SUCCESSFUL'
                  AND t2.executiondate >= (Now() - interval '1 MONTH') )
```